# Injecting external CSS links into a document, overriding certain existing sheets

Tags: html, css, stylesheet

A site exists for which I must re-style the front-end "template" using existing markup, but with an updated design. What I hope to do is somehow inject my own locally-written CSS style sheets onto the page so that my styles take over.

It seemed like a User Style Sheet would be the answer, but I was met with the following pitfalls:

- I often had to !important rules to make them stick, which won't happen once my styles replace those that are existing.
- I cannot link to local images.

I do not have a local development environment of the site available to me. The best I can do is wget mirror the site locally and edit the styles from there.. but I would prefer to restyle the existing markup if possible.

Any suggestions for a browser plugin or similar would be appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible. Take a look at the document.styleSheets property. It contains a object tree that is all of the CSS on the page. You can change individual properties of someone else's style sheet, or link to a local one entirely.

Here's a link http://www.javascriptkit.com/domref/stylesheet.shtml to start, but I would google for some better resources as-well.

document.styleSheets[0].href = 'file://js/newstyles.css'

Comment: This gave me the hint I needed, but didn't solve the problem. Unfortunately the 'href' property is read-only, so I ended up doing some processing and rebuilding the stylesheet stack using user-styles in Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

css terminal http://barberboy.github.com/css-terminal/